# Creating a Docx file using Officegen with html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, docx

I'm using officegen to create a docx file with Node.js. I'm adding images, lines, paragraphs, the issue that I have is that I have html with simple style like bold texxt, lists, and so on.

I've tried to use Textversion.js and it removes all the styling.

How can I convert that to be able to add it to the word doc without loosing the style? Any other tool that I can use?

Comment: Please post the code you are trying to use. Without any code don't aspect any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem using https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js. Using this package I was able to use html from server side and generate a docx file keeping the html styling. It is not compatible with google docs, but once you open the file with Microsoft Word and sabe it, you can upload it to google docs or use with any other free tool like OpenOffice. 
Thanks.